# Associating a CComboBox with a CRadioButton option on a CTaskDialog

Tags: mfc, taskdialog

I have been playing around with the [`CTaskDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctaskdialog-class?view=vs-2017). At the moment I have this:

[image: Task Dialog]

The code at the moment is quite simple:

```cpp
CTaskDialog dlg(_T("Reminder 1.\n\nReminder 2."), 
                _T("Important! Please read!"), 
                _T("Reminder"), TDCBF_YES_BUTTON | TDCBF_NO_BUTTON);

dlg.SetMainIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);
dlg.AddRadioButton(12345, _T("Delete reminder"));
dlg.AddRadioButton(12346, _T("Repeat reminder"));
dlg.SetFooterIcon(TD_INFORMATION_ICON);
dlg.SetFooterText(_T("This is footer text"));
dlg.DoModal();
```

I would like to get the **Repeat reminder** command line to have a drop-down combo associated with it so that the user can specify the number of weeks before repeating.

I don't know if this is possible with task dialog's.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. These Task Dialogs are pretty limited.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ok, thanks for confirming.

Comment: You can add a custom button or hyperlink to the dialog. On click show a popup menu to select the number of weeks. Just an idea. If you go so far it's propably the same effort as creating your own dialog which could have a better UX.

Comment: @zett42 Actually the thought occurs to me to just have a few radio choices to repeat the reminder x weeks.